# Formula for a rotated hyperbola

Tags: functions, transformation

Given this hyperbola $x^2 - y^2 = 1$, I want to rotate it by $45°$ (so the curve is only in the 1st and 3rd quadrant). How to write the formula of my new hyperbola. And can I find which rational function this new rotated hyperbola represents?

I know there is a way to rotate hyperbolas with matrices, but I would like to avoid that, since we haven't discussed the topic yet in class.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that with the 45-degree transformed coordinates $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(u+v),\>\>\>\>\>y=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(u-v)$. the equation becomes, $2uv = 1$.

Thus, after a 45-degree rotation, the hyperbola $x^2 - y^2 = 1$ become,

$$xy = \frac12$$

Comment: What do $u$ and $v$ represent?

Comment: The coordinates in the rotated axis